# Neatly listing values in multiple lines

Tags: tcl

How does one list values in multiple lines without a backslash at the end of each line?

One can't create a list in multiple lines without having a backslash at the end.
For example, the following (*wrong*) code:

```
set pets [list 
    cat
    dog
    elephant
]
```

gives an error:

```
invalid command name "cat"
    while executing
"cat"
    invoked from within
"set pets [list
        cat
        dog
        elephant
]"
```

It can be fixed by appending a backslash at the end of the line:

```
set pets [list \
    cat \
    dog \
    elephant \
]
```

Which is ugly and prone to errors.

Please note that:

- I'm aware of using the curly braces (`{` & `}`), but it doesn't allows executing commands and also keeps redundant whitespace characters.
- Any other command may be used (e.g. `dict create`), not only `list` as in my example.

Using Tcl 8.5

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Tcl uses newline (and semicolon) as a command separator. This is a core part of the basic syntax; you can't work around it so you *must* use either double quotes or braces to avoid backslash-itis. Let's look at the possibilities (remember, list separators can be any non-empty whitespace sequence).

### Ugly, error prone `list` with backslashes

```
set pets [list \
    cat \
    dog \
    $elephant \
]
```

### With braces, no substitutions

```
set pets {
    cat
    dog
    $elephant
}
```

(Note that in above, `$elephant` is just a sequence of characters, *not* a variable read.)

### With double quotes, substitutions but be careful!

```
set pets "
    cat
    dog
    $elephant
"
```

By “be careful!” I mean that where you have a multi-word member of the list, you need an inner `[list …]` or other quoting:

```
set pets "
    cat
    dog
    [list $elephant]
    [list "elephant's child"]
"
```

But this would be true with the `list`+backslashes at the top.

### Using `subst`…

```
set pets [subst {
    cat
    dog
    $elephant
    "elephant's child"
}]
```

I might “clean that up” (and avoid other potential problems) with:

```
set pets [list {*}[subst {
    cat
    dog
    [list $elephant]
    [list "elephant's child"]
}]]
```

But frankly, if things are getting really complex then I *actually* do this:

### Construct with several commands

```
set pets {
    cat
    dog
}
lappend pets $elephant "elephant's child"
```

No point in bashing yourself over the head to use one command when two or more will do everything with fewer problems.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes just making multiple lappends to split lines can be "neat".

```
set pets ""
lappend pets cat
lappend pets dog
lappend pets elephant

foreach pet $pets {
   puts "I like to eat ${pet}s"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proc called `lines` that might do what you're looking for—

```
proc lines {lines} {
    foreach item [uplevel [list subst -nobackslash $lines]] {
        lappend list $item
    }
    return $list
}
```

Here's a demonstration of its use—

```
set another_pet fish;

set pets [lines {
    cat
    [string range hotdog 3 end]
    elephant
    $another_pet
    "african pygmy hedgehog"
    snapping\ turtle
    "\"henry\" the bengali tiger"
}]

puts $pets
```

It outputs, as desired,

```
cat dog elephant fish {african pygmy hedgehog} {snapping turtle} {"henry" the bengali tiger}
```

An Ideone is [here](http://ideone.com/pl0dht) if you'd like to play around with a fork.

Comment: I'd use `list subst $list` instead of `subst {$list}` in there.

Comment: I edited the answer to add `-nobackslash` to `subst` as this produced behaviour closer to what I'd expect. (Updated example reflects this.) @DonalFellows, so the full line would be, `foreach item \[[list subst -nobackslash $list]] {`, correct? Do you recommend this stylistically, or for some other purpose as well?

Answer (score 0):

This took me all day but it finally was simple (of course).

```
proc render {infile outfile} {
    global ffconfig

    # ffmpeg options
    set a {                 
    -hide_banner                  
    -loglevel $ffconfig(loglevel) 
    -i $infile                    
    -tune $ffconfig(tune)         
    -movflags $ffconfig(movflags) 
    -preset $ffconfig(preset)     
    -c:v $ffconfig(vcodec)        
    -maxrate $ffconfig(max_rate)  
    -bufsize $ffconfig(buffsize)  
    -c:a $ffconfig(acodec)        
    -c:s $ffconfig(scodec)        
    -threads $ffconfig(threads)
    }

    # turn into an executable command line
    
    set b [list {*}$a];      # turn into a list of strings
    set c [subst $b];        # substitute values for variables
    puts stderr \[$c\]      # see below
    
    exec -- ffmpeg {*}$c $outfile ;
```

The *subst* command takes the list and processes it to
replace all the variables with their values like this:

```
[-hide_banner -loglevel {error} -i {The.Astrologer.1976.mkv} -tune {film} -movflags {faststart} -preset {slow} -c:v {libx264} -maxrate {8192} -bufsize {8000k} -c:a {copy} -c:s {copy} -threads {2}]
```

the {*}$c  command expands the list elements.